# how to reinitialize log shipping?

Tags: transaction-log

Here is the situation:

DB on Server A had the transaction log shipping configured and uses Server B as secondary. It has been working well for a long time.

However, we recently detected that one of the trn files got corrupted and Server B cannot restore it.

DB on Server A is still healthy, so I would like to create a new full backup into Server B and restart the transaction log shipping.

Since all the timings and other settings were already tweaked and configured, I am trying to avoid starting from scratch.

What step would i need to follow in order to reinitialize the log shipping? (This is a SQL Servert 2008 R2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Disable the log shipping jobs on both servers.
2. Back up the database on Server A.
3. Restore the database with the backup you just created and `with norecovery` on Server B.
4. Re-enable the log shipping jobs on both servers.

Comment: Actually I figured it out before reading your answer. Anyway, Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I have an existing full backup from last night and all the log files have already been shipped to the secondary server.  It's just out of sync.

Can I:
1. copy the existing full backup to the secondary server.
2. disable the log shipping on both servers.
3. Restore with no-recovery and include all the log files on the secondary. 
4. Re-enable the log shipping jobs.

Seems like that should work but I've never tried it.